# Windows 10 boot, how can you see what is happening?

Tags: windows-10, boot, services, gui, init

In all the Desktop Linux distros I have used (debian based, redhat based, etc) the boot screen is graphical with some sort of progress bar.

The cool thing is that you can choose to hit a keyboard button and then the progress bar is replaced with a screen that shows what the boot up is doing (showing all the various programs that need to be run (networking, dbus, mounting, etc etc)).

In Windows 10 you also get a graphical boot screen. Instead of a progressbar you get a indefinite-progressbar.

I would very much like to see what is happening as it happens (instead of the indefinite-progressbar). **Is there a way to see what is happening during Windows-10 boot? If yes, how can you see what is happening?**

Comment: if you guys have a better idea for a better title feel free to suggest... the current title is kind of generic and I feel like it won't google very well.

Comment: capture a boot log with  procmon or WPRUI/Windows Perf Toolkit, this tells you what windows is doing during boot.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. The only exception would be to boot into safe mode which does show you some of the components that are being loaded.

After you successfully logged into the system you could check the Event Log for information what happened.

Answer (score 1):

As always, use caution when editing the Windows registry, if you edit the wrong thing, your machine may become unbootable.

To use enable verbose status messages by editing the registry, follow these steps:

Click Start > Run.

In the Open box, type regedit, and then click OK.

Locate and then click the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.

Type verbosestatus, and then press ENTER.

Double-click the new key that you created, type 1 in the Value data box, and then click OK.

Quit Registry Editor.

[SOURCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/enable-verbose-startup-shutdown-logon-logoff-status-messages)

Comment: This does not work. I've tried it many times over the years. It probably did something back in the XP days.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Local Group Policy Editor (search on "gpo") and go to GPO -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System [Scroll to the bottom] -> Display highly detailed status messages. Click on "policy setting" and then the "Enabled" radio button, then OK.

Comment: This does not work. I've tried it many times over the years. It probably did something back in the XP days.